# automating loading of multiple *.mat files & matrix resize

Tags: matlab, matlab-load

I have a ton of data that needs to be processed from lab work. I have a ton of .mat files that contain a signal matrix of dimensions 7 x w. I need to resize the matrix to 7 x N and w is larger and smaller than N to make the rest of the analysis easier (don't care about data past N). I have the psuedocode of how I want this to work but don’t know how to implement it. Any help would be great thanks!

Folder structure of all my data:

Main folder

```
Alpha 1
    1111.mat
    1321.mat
Alpha 2
    1010.mat
    1234.mat
    1109.mat
    933.mat
Alpha 3
    1223.mat
```

etc.

Psudeocode:

```
    Master_matrix = []
    For all n *.mat
        Load n'th *.mat from alpha 1
        If w > N
            Resize matrix down to N
        Else
            Zero pad to N
        End if
    Master_matrix = master_matrix .+ new resized matrix
    End for

rest of my code...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to generate the file list. I have my own function for that, but there is, for example, [GETFILELIST](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25610-list-files-with-specified-suffix) or the excellent interactive [UIPICKFILES](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10867-uipickfiles-uigetfile-on-steroids) to generate the list of files.

Once you have the file list (I'll assume it's a cell array containing the filenames), you can do the following:

```
nFiles = length(fileList);
Master_matrix = zeros(7,N);

for iFile = 1:nFiles
    %# if all files contain a variable of the same name, 
    %# you can simplify the loading by not assigning an output
    %# in the load command, and call the file by
    %# its variable name (i.e. replace 'loadedData')
    tmp = load(fileList{iFile});
    fn = fieldnames(tmp);
    loadedData = tmp.(fn{1});

    %# find size 
    w = size(loadedData,2);

    if w>=N
       Master_matrix = Master_matrix + loadedData(:,1:N);
    else
       %# only adding to the first few columns is the same as zero-padding
       Master_matrix(:,1:w) = Master_matrix(:,1:w) = loadedData;
    end
end
```

Note: In case you don't actually want to add up the data, but simply store it in the master array, you can make `Master_matrix` into a 7-by-N-by-nFiles array, where the nth plane of `Master_matrix` is the content of the nth file. In this case, you'd initialize `Master_matrix` as

```
Master_matrix = zeros(7,N,nFiles);
```

and you'd write the if-clause as

```
    if w>=N
       Master_matrix(:,:,iFile) = Master_matrix(:,:,iFile) + loadedData(:,1:N);
    else
       %# only adding to the first few columns is the same as zero-padding
       Master_matrix(:,1:w,iFile) = Master_matrix(:,1:w,iFile) = loadedData;
    end
```

Also note that you might want to initialize `Master_matrix` as `NaN` instead of `zeros`, so that the zeros don't affect subsequent statistics (if that's what you want to do with the data).